# Checkbox array, can't update multiple rows in foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

I'm having some problems with updating rows in my database.

I have a form of multiple checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="75">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="76">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="77">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="78">
```

Now, i want to update those rows that is selected with the checkboxes.
The columnname is "pm_id", and the tablename is "pm". "to_removed" is the columnname that i wish to update.

```
$data = array(
    'to_removed' => 1
);
$checked = $this->input->post('checkbox');
foreach($checked as $check)
{               
    $this->db->where('pm_id', $check);
$this->db->update('pm', $data); 

}
```

Now, even if i select every checkbox, it only deletes one. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you give some insight in your db class? Because it looks quite unclear to me how it works. It seems to do some magic with the where clause for the update function, but what is that magic? Also, have you tried using var_dump() on the $checked array, and seeing what is actually in there?

Comment: It seems like it takes the same value, 
array
  0 => string '82' (length=2)
  1 => string '82' (length=2)

Answer (score -1):

Just found the problem. Seems like every checkbox had the same value :D

EDIT: What i meant was, the code above wasn't mine exactly. Mine had just other values.